Why I can not connect connect with java.sql.DriveManager in Kotlin?
I want to connect MySQL database with java.sql.DriverManager in Kotlin code.
Here is info about connection in MySQL.

Connection name:GCP
username:dev
password:0000
port: 3306


Here is my simple code in Kotlin.
package org.example;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

//TIP To <b>Run</b> code, press <shortcut actionId="Run"/> or
// click the <icon src="AllIcons.Actions.Execute"/> icon in the gutter.
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            var availableDrivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
            System.out.println("Drivers available");
            while(availableDrivers.hasMoreElements()){
                var driver = availableDrivers.nextElement();
                System.out.println(driver);
            }
            System.out.println("end of Drivers available");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        //var url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestConnection1";
        //var user = "root";
        //var password = "MySQLJay30";

        var url = "jdbc:mysql://35.194.200.2:3306/GCP";
        var user = "dev";
        var password = "0000";
        try{
            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            var connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Connected");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

In IntelliJ, the output of console is as follows.
11:16:47 AM: Executing ':org.example.Main.main()'...

> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes

> Task :org.example.Main.main()
Drivers available
end of Drivers available
Connecting to database...
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://35.194.200.2:3306/GCP

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 581ms
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
11:16:48 AM: Execution finished ':org.example.Main.main()'.

I also checked that I have added mysql-connector-j-9.0.0.jar which I downloaded from Maven

I looked at the JDBC powerpoint and java.sql.DriverManager API (Java SE 11) yesterday.
Checking the syntax of


Add mysql-connector-j-9.0.0 as a gradle dependency not in the IntelliJ libraries. implementation group: 'com.mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-j', version: '9.0.0'

As originally posted as a comment by seenukarthi:

Add mysql-connector-j-9.0.0 as a gradle dependency not in the
IntelliJ libraries. implementation group: 'com.mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-j', version: '9.0.0'

By adding the library in IntelliJ, it is not seen or used by Gradle. Your console output shows it was run with Gradle, which means only the libraries known to Gradle are used on the classpath, so the MySQL Connector/J dependency isn't there.
